# How to copy row, insert tow under then paste data?

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy, paste

I have code that runs through column E (Column C in example below) and searches for any change in data. It then inserts a blank row under that change and loops through the set of data (200-500 rows long).

I want a "copy and paste" feature of the last row of data, before the change, into the newly inserted row.

Before:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | Chase | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Chase | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | Ben | 9 |

After:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | 2 |
|  | 2 | Sally |  |
| 1 | 2 | Chase | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Chase | 4 |
|  | 2 | Chase |  |
| 1 | 2 | Ben | 9 |
|  | 2 | Ben |  |

The code I have has a loop:

```vb
Sub CleanUpPart2()

'Insert Rows by column F

'
    Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
    Dim oRng As Range

    Set oRng = Range("f1")

    iRow = oRng.Row
    iCol = oRng.Column

    Do
'
    If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        iRow = iRow + 2
    Else
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
'
    Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**:

Try the updated code, please:

```
Sub testInsertRowCopyBefore()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For i = lastRow + 1 To 3 Step -1
    If sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> sh.Range("C" & i - 1).Value Then
        sh.Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Insert xlUp
        sh.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Value = sh.Range("B" & i - 1 & ":C" & i - 1).Value
    End If
   Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that "Column A", "Column B" and "Column C" are the headers, which stay on the sheet first row.

Please, test it and send some feedback